# Binding Writeable bitmap to canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to write a simple WPF program to implement Conway's Game of Life.
My Window consists of a toolbar and a canvas with and embedded Image, on which I'm trying to display a writeable bitmap.

I have a button on the toolbar which, when clicked,  updates a single generation and then displays the resulting bitmap on the canvas image. I update the image directly with

```
img.Source = wbmp;
```

This works without a problem.

However, I'd like to show the ongoing updates, without having to click the "Update" button each time. So I tried implementing a loop of 10 iterations. However, the updated image is only shown after the 10th iteration is completed (i.e. I don;t see the first 9 generations)

My understanding is that I need to bind the Image control to the Writeable bitmap in order to "force" an update each generation. I've tried this with the code below - but now nothing displays at all. Initially I found that the PropertyChanged event didn't seem to be firing but I had no method assigned so, I added PropertyChanged **= delegate {}**;  (I did this because the Internet told me to!)

I am really not sure where I'm going wrong. I'm rather clueless about WPF and binding in particular. (Much of my code is adapted copy-pasta.) Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<Canvas Name ="canvas" Grid.Row="1" Background="LightGray">
    <Image Name="img" Source="{Binding GoLImage}"/>
</Canvas>

public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    private ImageSource golImage;  //writeable bitmap;

    public ImageSource GoLImage
    {
        get { return golImage; }
        set
        {
            golImage = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(GoLImage)));
        }
    }

}

 private void Button_Run10_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BitmapPixelMaker bmp = new BitmapPixelMaker(1200, 800);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            goL.UpdateLifeGrid();  //goL is an instance of my class implementing the Game of Life
            goL.LifeGridTobmp(bmp);
            WriteableBitmap wbmp = bmp.MakeBitmap(96, 96);

            //Trying to display bitmap
            MyViewModel golDisplay = new MyViewModel();
            golDisplay.GoLImage = wbmp; //This doesn't automatically display on each iteration

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop in your Button Click handler blocks the UI thread. And you have not assigned the view model instance to the DataContext property of the view.

Use a DispatcherTimer with a Tick event handler like shown below.

Do not create a new view model instance and a new WriteableBitmap in each cycle, but just modify the existing one - you should therefore change the view model property declaration to `public WriteableBitmap GoLImage` so that the ModifyBitmap method can access it.

```
private readonly MyViewModel golDisplay = new MyViewModel();

private readonly DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer
{
    Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1)
};

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    golDisplay.GoLImage = WriteableBitmap(1200, 800, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default, null);
    DataContext = golDisplay;

    timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
    timer.Start(); // optionally, call Start/Stop in a Button Click handler
}

private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bmp = new BitmapPixelMaker(1200, 800);

    goL.UpdateLifeGrid();
    goL.LifeGridTobmp(bmp);

    ModifyBitmap(bmp); // write directly to golDisplay.GoLImage
}
```

---

An alternative to a DispatcherTimer might be an simple loop over an asynchronous and awaited update call.

Something like shown below, where the Update method would perform the CPU-intensive calculations and then return the new pixel buffer

```
private async void OnWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var buffer = await Task.Run(() => game.Update());

        bitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, game.Width, game.Height),
                           buffer, game.Stride, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply Clemens. I understand some of what you have said but am still confused by several things (due to my lack of knowledge, not your explanation!) However, the main thing is that your suggestions _work_ and that gives me something to go and try and understand further. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm still confused, or rather surprised, that using a DispatchTimer with a TickEvent  is the way to go. Is there no way of forcing an update within a loop? It seems "odd" that the updates have to occur at regular intervals dictated by the timer interval, rather than whenever the calculations performing the update are finished.

Comment: The rendering thread needs to get a chance to display the scene. Think of it as a movie that runs at a certain frame rate. While there are of course ways to do the calculations asynchronously and update the UI as soon as they are done, the frame rate would change all the time, depending on how long the calculation of each single cycle takes. You can of course always shorten the timer's Interval. However, anything below 10 ms won't make sense.

Comment: Thanks Clemens - the "constant frame rate" makes sense.

Comment: You're welcome. You may also want to take a look at [this example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap?view=netcore-3.1#examples) for how to asynchronously write into the WriteableBitmap's BackBuffer.

Comment: Just played around a bit with a GoL implementation and found that it runs great when you just do the update asynchronously and update the WriteableBitmap immedialety. See the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Clemens - I think that's exactly what I was wanting in the first place. I'll definitely try that. (But even your first answer was very helpful indeed as it pointed me to a lot of things I wasn't aware of.) Greatly appreciate all your help; it's been extremely useful.

Comment: And it was fun to implement this again, after quite a long time. Let me know if you want to know how to dispatch the calculations to multiple threads by either Parallel.For or Task.WhenAll :-)

Comment: Ha! I've already managed to get the Parallel.For working without any trouble at all :-)
(But I'll be posting another problem shortly about a MouseLeftButtonUp event not seeming to fire :-)